# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Is there a way to get the controller name from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Like, lets say I have the model called: `Vehicle`.
Is there any command such as `Vehicle.controller` that would return `:vehicles_controller` or `"vehicles_controller"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but its easy to create such a helper:

```
def controllerize(model)
  "#{model.name.tableize}_controller"
end
```

Better question is why do you want it? Sounds like a bit of a code smell—there aren't a lot of good reasons for your model to know anything about your controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Why? It's routes that determines paths not models.

Making your model aware of routes makes no sense at all. Models are there to deal with business logic and data. Routes are the domain of controllers.

If you have a route defined as `resource :vehicles` in your routes.rb then you have routes available to you in the form of `vehicle_path`, `vehicles_path` etc... to find out what routes you have just run `rake routes` from your command line in your apps root folder.

Comment: jamesw is spot-on. I just don't see a rational need for such a helper that doesn't point to an antipattern.

Comment: yeah, as it turns out, I don't really need it. But, the selected answer answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a naming convention and good practice that gets you some things for free, for doing it the Rails way, that a controller for User model is often called UsersController. If you keep with a convention, then you can write a method that does that for you. Otherwise, the answer is: "No, sorry".